# PHP ajax loading result and pagination with sorting

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have this working script to get members list via Ajax auto loading and pagination the results.

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#results").load("get_result.php"); 
  $("#results").on("click",".paginations a", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
    $("#results").load("get_result.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
    });
  });
});
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <h1>Name</h1>
  <p>Age</p>
  <p>City</p>
  <p>ID</p>
</div>
```

Now, I need to add - sorting by - option to same code:

```
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="sortby(age)">Age</button></li>
  <li><button onclick="sortby(name)">Name</button></li>
  <li><button onclick="sortby(city)">City</button></li>
  .....
</ul>
```

I tried as my AJAX knowledge -low :)- with below code And its working fine (Result and Pagination) as default with no Sorting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sortby="";
  $("#results").load("get_result.php",{"sortby":sortby}); 
  $("#results").on("click",".paginations a", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page=$(this).attr("data-page");
    $("#results").load("get_result.php",{"sortby":sortby,"page":page}, function(){ 
    });
  });
});
```

**PHP:** - *no problem with PHP at all.*

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  if ($_POST['sortby']){
    $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE city=? ORDER BY city DESC");
    ............
  } else {
    $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER by id");
    ............
  }
}
```

**So, How I can passing/calling sortBy value to inside ajax?**

Answer (score 0):

you can pass sortby on ajax url, for example $("#results").load("get_result.php?sortby=name") and take that parameter on your server side

Answer (score 0):

There is a very powerful jquery plugin by the name of Datatable to achieve the required functionality.
Visit The [link](https://datatables.net/)
Just you have to grab your table id and call Datatable function i.e

```
  $('#yourTable').DataTable("order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]); // Where 1 is you column number by which you want to sort.
```

It has lots of builtin functionality you can play with it very easily.

Comment: Thank Sajjad, But output it's not table, it's div card with photo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var results = $("#results");
    var page = 1;
    function ajaxLoad(resultHtml){
        var resultObj = $(resultHtml);
        results.empty().append(resultObj);
        var paginations = resultObj.find('.paginations a');
        paginations.click(function(e){
            page = $(this).attr("data-page");
            $.post('get_result.php',{"page":page},function(resultHtml){
                ajaxLoad(resultHtml);
            });
            return false;
        });
        /* Different way 
        *  <li><button onclick="sortby(age)">Age</button></li>... change to 
        *   <li><button class="sortby" data-sortby="age">Age</button></li>
        *
        var sortbyObj = resultObj.find('.sortby');
        sortbyObj.click(function(){
            var dataSortby =$(this).attr("data-sortby");
            $.post('get_result.php',{"page":page, sortby:dataSortby},function(resultHtml){
                ajaxLoad(resultHtml);
            });
        });
        */
    }
    function sortby(val){
        $.post('get_result.php',{"page":page, "sortby":val},function(resultHtml){
            ajaxLoad(resultHtml);
        });
    }
    $.post('get_result.php',{"page": page},function(resultHtml){
        ajaxLoad(resultHtml);
    });
});
```

The code has not been tested